# dynamic chaining sweetalert2

Tags: dynamic, queue, sweetalert2, chain

I want to chained alerts via json. I have this:

```
[
    {"mes":"there are <strong>3<\/strong> messages.", "ico":"info"},
    {"mes":"message1","ico":"error"},
    {"mes":"message2","ico":"success"}
    {"mes":"message3","ico":"warning"}
]
```

I want to generate 4 alerts for this json one after another. I tried with jquery.each but no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

that was ridiculously easy.

i sent data from php like this:

```
echo json_encode([
    {"mes":"there are <strong>3<\/strong> messages.", "ico":"info"},
    {"mes":"message1","ico":"error"},
    {"mes":"message2","ico":"success"}
    {"mes":"message3","ico":"warning"}
]);
```

and parse like this:

```
swal.queue(JSON.parse(data);
```

so i achieved what i want.